# How do I force fetching of tags if I have the --no-tags option set

Tags: git, git-config, git-fetch

Whenever I run `git fetch` it fetches all the tags from origin. In a project with lots of tags, this can get quite bothersome. So I ran `git config remote.origin.tagopt --no-tags` so fetching will no-longer fetch tags.

However, there are some times when I do want to fetch tags, or a single tag. Does anyone know how to do this? (besides removing that configuration, and running `git fetch --no-tags` every time)

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To fetch a single tag, you can use `git fetch <remote-name> tag <tag-name>`.